# Asp.net GridView index not accurate when returning to the page (back button) after DB row deleted

Tags: asp.net, gridview, back-button

I have a Gridview in asp.net that shows filtered information from a DB. The grid has a link button that directs to an Information page.

When the user changes the data at the information page (which makes that data no longer fit the original filter from the main page) and then hits the "back" button - it returns to the main gridview, and still shows the original data (including that changed row that is no longer relevant to the filter). That is fine by me.
The thing is the if I click that changed row, it now direct the page to the row underneath it, and the same goes to all the other rows under the changed row - they all direct to the row above them, as if the deleted row is not there.
Is this something known with gridviews or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: but, on row click, you grabbing the database PK row id to resolve what to display on the target page, right? I mean, how does that 2nd target page even care, or know or worry about what "index" was from the previous page? I would assume a simple button click in the gv row occurs, that then gets the pk id, and that PK id is passed to the target page, which in turn loads the data based on some database PK value. (I mean, how else could you make this reliably work, right???).

Comment: Yes, that is part of the "weirdness" - because on row click it grabs the first column, which contains the pk, and passes it to the 2nd page.

So, somehow, it grabs the pk the the row above instead of its own,  as if it knows the data has changed (even though no update accured in that page).